# Having issue with smiley's integration in android

Tags: android, emoticons

In my app i need to integrate commenting functionality which includes smiley.And i am successfully showing the smiley's in android edit text box.But i am struck at... after writing the complete comment with smiley's user will click send.After user clicking the enter i need to send the comment as a text(need to replace smile with its code as string like ":-)") 
. How to convert that smiley image to its respective code. Please any one help me to get out of this.

And to convert text to smileys i am using the bellow code

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(
    cstlistemoji.images[index]);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                return d;
            }
        };
        cs = Html.fromHtml(
                "<img src='"
                        + getResources()
                                .getDrawable(cstlistemoji.images[index])
                        + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
        System.out.println("cs is:- " + cs);
        edttxtemoji.append(cs);
```

Comment: You can map that images to String in HashMap

Comment: Thanks Hardik Trivedi..Can u please attach some code if any..